# How to use space_group for Quantum Espresso

Tags: quantum-espresso

I have a structure created in `pymatgen` with the following properties:

```
from pymatgen.core.structure import Structure
from pymatgen.symmetry.analyzer import SpacegroupAnalyzer

lattice = [
    [ 2.465669985, 0.000000000,   0.000000000],
    [-1.232834994, 2.135332846,   0.000000000],
    [ 0.000000000, 0.000000000,   20.00000010],
]

species = ["C", "C"]

coords = [
    [0.000000000, 0.000000000, 0.250000000],
    [0.333333333, 0.666666667, 0.250000000],
]

structure = Structure(
    lattice=lattice,
    species=species,
    coords=coords,
)
sym = SpacegroupAnalyzer(structure)
_spg_data = sym.get_symmetry_dataset()
isg_number = _spg_data["number"]

print()
print(structure)
print(f"isg_number: {isg_number}")
```

which gives:

```
Full Formula (C2)
Reduced Formula: C
abc   :   2.465670   2.465670  20.000000
angles:  90.000000  90.000000 120.000000
Sites (2)
  #  SP           a         b     c
---  ----  --------  --------  ----
  0  C     0         0         0.25
  1  C     0.333333  0.666667  0.25
isg_number: 191
```

I am attempting to utilise the `space_group` option for potential performance speed-up. In this I have two Q.E. files which I hope would give equivalent results; however, the final energies differ. In the first file I use `ibrav = 0`:

```
&CONTROL
    calculation = 'scf'
    outdir = '/tmp/'
    prefix = 'graphene'
    pseudo_dir = 'pbe'
    restart_mode='from_scratch'
/
&SYSTEM
    ibrav = 0
    nat = 2, ntyp = 1,
    ecutwfc = 40.0 ,
    ecutrho = 400.0 ,
    occupations = 'smearing', degauss = 0.0001, smearing = 'marzari-vanderbilt'
/
&ELECTRONS
    conv_thr = 1.0d-10,
    mixing_beta = 0.3,
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
C 12.01 C.upf
CELL_PARAMETERS angstrom
   2.465669985   0.000000000   0.000000000
  -1.232834994   2.135332846   0.000000000
   0.000000000   0.000000000   20.00000010
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
C 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.250000000
C 0.333333333 0.666666667 0.250000000
K_POINTS automatic
12 12 1 0 0 0
```

In the second I use `space_group = 191`.

```
&CONTROL
    calculation = 'scf'
    outdir = '/tmp/'
    prefix = 'graphene'
    pseudo_dir = 'pbe'
    restart_mode='from_scratch'
/
&SYSTEM
    space_group = 191
    A = 2.465669985
    B = 2.465669985
    C = 20.00000010
    nat = 2, ntyp = 1,
    ecutwfc = 40.0 ,
    ecutrho = 400.0 ,
    occupations = 'smearing', degauss = 0.0001, smearing = 'marzari-vanderbilt'
/
&ELECTRONS
    conv_thr = 1.0d-10,
    mixing_beta = 0.3,
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
C 12.01 C.upf
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal_sg
C 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.250000000
C 0.333333333 0.666666667 0.250000000
K_POINTS automatic
12 12 1 0 0 0
```

For the graphene example above, where layers are separated by a 20 A gap I get two very different crystal structures (see answers[1]). What has gone wrong, and how do I replicate the first example using `space_group` as the option?

[1][https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/12410/translate-between-ibrav-and-space-group-quantum-espresso-inputs/12411?noredirect=1#comment27589_12411]